# Splitting the tag "modular" to "-arithmetic" and "-design"

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [modular](/questions/tagged/modular) tag needs to be split into [modular-arithmetic](/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic) and [modular-design](/questions/tagged/modular-design). There are these two distinctly different types of answers there.

I've started a little bit, could someone please continue with this? Every bit helps.

Comment: After just creating the [tag:modular-design] tag, I wonder if we shouldn't be using the [tag:modularity] tag instead? Perhaps these two should be synonymized?